# Update a row with unique condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have to update a row with condition where the message ID will be unique.
How do i write a query for the same.
I mean to say if the message id Is unique ,then only the row has to get updated and the column named flag in the table has to get updated as "1".
The table is temp table hence the value will not be stored into the same.
Also the update statement executes at the end of the stored procedure.
Basically it is used as the record updated once should not come into picture in next run.

For Ex:

```
Update table [Tablename ] set FLAG='1' where messageID =' message id has to be unique'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Count(1)OVER(partition BY messageID) AS cnt,*
         FROM   [Tablename])
UPDATE cte
SET    FLAG = '1'
WHERE  cnt = 1
```

`Count(1)OVER(partition BY messageID)` will return the count of each `messageID` in your table. update the `flag` when count is `1`